# Dynamically attach a plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I have a problem on my development website www.depcore.com/v4 I have a form with a slider plugin.

I wanted to be as easy as possible so I used a slider plugin for the budget.

After sending the form I replace it with a thank you/info message with the ability to resend it.

The base form is stored in a variable.

Here is the fragment that sends and replaces the form

```
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    $('#contactForm').html("<div id='message-sent'></div>");
                    $('#message-sent').html("<div><h2>Thank you</h2> <p>The message was sent.  I'll get back to you as soon as possible</p></div><p><a href='#'>Send another</a></p></div>").hide().fadeIn(1500);
                    $('#message-sent a').live('click',function(){
                        $('#contactForm').html(formF).fadeIn(1500); return false;
                        jQuery("#budget").slider({ from: 100, to: 10000, step: 100,  scale: [100, '|', 2500, '|' , '5000', '|', 7500, '|', 10000],
 round: 1, dimension: '&nbsp;$'});
                    });
                }
            });
```

I guess it has to do with the live function and is probably very easy, but couldn't make much sens out of the documentation.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `return false;` within your `live()` before `jQuery("#budget").slider(...)` should solve the problem.

But you don't have to use `live` in your case, because you are explicitly setting the slider in your `success`handler. You can use `.click()` here. You could use `$('#message-sent a').live(...)` in some "global code".

Comment: now thats embarrassing :) I didn't notice that. Thanks for all the help (the additional code too). All works fine now.